# Error while creating procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

This is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test_final7() 

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO chef_ratings(`chef_id`,`avg_total_no_votes`,`avg_total_rating`,`no_of_votes`,`avg_rating`) 
    SELECT `chef_id`, (SELECT count(chef_id) FROM rates) / ( SELECT count(DISTINCT chef_id) FROM rates) ,
    ( ( SELECT sum( (`question_1` + `question_2` +`question_3` ) /3 ) FROM rates ) / ( SELECT count(chef_id) FROM rates) ),
    ( SELECT count(chef_id) FROM rates ),avg( (`question_1`+`question_2`+`question_3`) /3 )
    FROM rates 
    GROUP BY `chef_id`;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting error :

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE sp_test_final6()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `chef_ratings`( `chef_id`, `avg_t' at line 1
```

Any idea why it is failing?

**Edited:** It works fine in mysql version 5.5 but Server version: 4.1.22 it is giving this problem. How we can fix without upgrading?

Comment: How can you even read this code. Add some breaks and proper indenting, and you will probably spot your error yourself.

Comment: Its messy even I tried to format the code myself on my machine and its having too many `()` and looks like missing something while closing the brackets in sum() functions.

Comment: [*SPs are supported in MySQL since 5.0*](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569). So you can't build an SP in older version.